# Create React App - Router paths not serving javascript

Tags: amazon-s3, create-react-app

I have a CRA site that has been deployed to Amazon S3.

When the router paths have a / in the url the Javascript or CSS is no longer loading. (i.e. it's trying to load from example.com/subdomain/static rather than example.com/static)

I've tried setting PUBLIC_URL='/' in .env.production and that's not helping.

Any clues on how to get URLs working again.

Any

Comment: Have you set `homepage` in `package.json` file?

Comment: Have you deployed on sub-folder?

Answer (score 0):

homepage was not set correctly in package.json